# Is the Default ListView Group not automatically created?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I want to create a list of categories and map each category to a ListViewGroup.

As a start/stub, I've got this code ("listApplications" is a ListView):

```
private ListViewGroup GetGroupForCategoryName(string ACategoryName) {
  return listApplications.Groups[0];
}
```

...but I get, "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

Since a ListView has a default group (so I've read), I assumed that element 0 would be that default group. Do I need to explicitly create the default group so that 0 is not out of range, or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the groups using the Smart Tag or in code and then assign. I do not believe there is a group set by default. Ensure that the control is in Details View.

*VB*

```
ListView1.ShowGroups = True
ListView1.View = View.Details

Dim iFirstGroup As Integer, iSecondGroup As Integer

iFirstGroup = ListView1.Groups.Add(New ListViewGroup("Test 1"))
iSecondGroup = ListView1.Groups.Add(New ListViewGroup("Test 2"))

ListView1.Columns.Add("Test Col")

ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem("I'm in Group 1") With {.Group = ListView1.Groups(iFirstGroup)})
ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem("I'm in Group 2") With {.Group = ListView1.Groups(iSecondGroup)})
```

*C#*

```
listView1.ShowGroups = true;
listView1.View = View.Details;

int iFirstGroup = 0;
int iSecondGroup = 0;

iFirstGroup = listView1.Groups.Add(new ListViewGroup("Test 1"));
iSecondGroup = listView1.Groups.Add(new ListViewGroup("Test 2"));

listView1.Columns.Add("Test Col");

ListViewItem lvi1 = new ListViewItem("I'm in Group 1");
lvi1.Group = listView1.Groups[iFirstGroup];

ListViewItem lvi2 = new ListViewItem("I'm in Group 2");
lvi2.Group = listView1.Groups[iSecondGroup];

listView1.Items.Add(lvi1);
listView1.Items.Add(lvi2);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.groups.aspx):

> To use the grouping feature, add one or more ListViewGroup objects to
>   the Groups collection of a ListView control. Set the group header text
>   and header alignment in the ListViewGroup constructor, or set them
>   using the ListViewGroup.Header and ListViewGroup.HeaderAlignment
>   properties.

So the example on MSDN can give you some advices.

Comment: Thanks; I knew that, but also read there is a Default Group. I thought the default group should be at index 0 in the Groups array.